# Why does Angularjs Service Return a Character Array instead of an Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using a service(.factory) to hold an array of objects/items which gets updated by multiple controllers and then the data is pulled back down by each controller.  Each time I add a new array of data, I push it onto the array.  However, when I attempt to load an array within my controller so I can display it my view, it is returning a character array which makes it impossible to use ng-repeat to iterate over the values.

```
// controllers.js
angular.module('myapp.controllers', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MainService) {
  $scope.mainItems = MainService.all(); // Why does this return a char array?

  // get the count
  $scope.getCount = function(item){
      return TempOrder.getCount(item);
  }

  // add an item
  $scope.addItem = function(item){
      TempOrder.addItem(item);
      return TempOrder.getCount(item);
  }

})
.controller('SecondaryCtrl', function($scope, MainService) {
   $scope.items = MainService.all(); // Why does this return a char array?

  // get the count
  $scope.getCount = function(item){
      return TempOrder.getCount(item);
  }

  // add an item
  $scope.addItem = function(item){
      TempOrder.addItem(item);
      return TempOrder.getCount(item);
  }
});
```

This is my service

```
// services.js
angular.module('myapp.services', [])

.factory('MainService', function() {

orderItems = [];

return {
   all: function() {
       return orderItems;  // Why does return a char array???
   },
   getCount: function(item){
      var count = 0;
      for (i = 0;i<orderItems.length;i++) {
        if (orderItems[i] === item ){
          count++;
        }
      }
     return count;
   },
   addItem: function(item) {
      orderItems.push(item);
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: what are you pushing in the array? What is `item` here? Also you're using something called `MainService` and instead defining `TempOrder`?

Comment: Also on the `getCount()` you're using the comparison `if (orderItems[i] === item ){` which makes me suspect you're storing simple strings instead of objects in your `orderItems` array.

Comment: I updated TempOrder to MainService, that was just a typo from me trying to clean up the code make things easier to read.  The objects I am storing are shopping cart items which have an `Id, Name, Price, Description`.  Earlier I tried to use `if (orderItems[i].id === item.id ){  `  , however it wasn't properly comparing and had to change it to just compare items.

Comment: that means the items aren't being stored as an object. Try doing a `console.log(item)` when you push them in the array. I suspect that only a character is being pushed instead of the `object`

Comment: This is the object I am pushing onto the orderItems array, this is what I got from doing a console.log(item) `{"id":"3","name":"Soda","price":"4.99","description":"A medium soda","create_time":"2015-03-23 01:48:50","update_time":"2015-03-25 23:31:01","categories_id":"2"}`

Comment: I am only using + and - symbols to add items to my array.  Do you think I need to define a model and set each model item to each attribute in the object?  Sort of like this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1488/) does?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your above code, but for some reasons getting `module not found` while adding in as a code snippet here.

Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3x0a8t4/4/) for your solution, I'm not sure what went wrong, but maybe it can be the html where your only passing in `item.name` or any key or maybe you haven't initialized your `$scope.item = {}` in the `controller` and that's why it remains undefined and the angular can't bind to it. Remember **Angular won't bind to values that are undefined on controller bootstrap**

Comment: So it appears as though I need to run it through the cloneObj function to properly convert it to an object before storing it in the array based on what you are saying.  But the one part I am still confused about is since I am passing back several key value pairs based on a single click (like clicking a + symbol) instead of having multiple fields which are each mapped to a specific model like item.name and item.id, is there any trick to it?  Do I need to create hidden fields that are populated with ng-init so that I can assign models like item.name and item.id to each hidden field?

Comment: No, cloning is only to avoid **pass by reference** issue in JS. Basically you can simply push in the object directly into the array and that will work. However when you **reset** your object back to an empty object, the object just pushed in will become empty because of the reference issue. That's why cloning is a better option before storing in an array.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help.  I implemented your method but the objects being pushed onto the array are character arrays, which is making it impossible to use them in another controller and display into another view.  Any suggestions?  I can display it in another controller but as `0: "{"1: """2: "i"3: "d"4: """5: ":"6: """7: "3"8: """` , so it is impossible to call it by the key name or the key id.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Arrays? I didn't get it! And for the comments you mentioned in your question, I would say yes store them as individual objects instead of character arrays. That would make things much simpler.

Comment: So when I pull stuff in via an http request the items come across as this `Object {id: "2", create_time: "2015-03-23 01:10:46", update_time: "2015-03-23 01:10:46", name: "Soda", price:"3.99"}`.  But when I then try to push that item to a different array of objects it changes its formatting so then it becomes `{"id":"1","name":"Soda","price":"3.99","create_time":"2015-03-23 01:48:50","update_time":"2015-03-25 23:29:41"}` , so it appears as though it is making everything into string values....am I understanding that right?  Would stripping the quotes from around the keys make it function right?

Comment: No stripping the strings from the key name doesn't makes any difference. Meaning if you create an object as `var obj = {'name' : 'something'}` will be same as `var obj = { name : 'something'}`. It's only the type of  the values that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to I_Debug_Everything for your help.  I realized that in my view I wasn't properly passing the item object. When passed the wrong way, it isn't passed as an object making it impossible to reference attributes of the item.  The right way passes the item as an object and therefore I can access stuff like item.name in my functions.

**WRONG WAY**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
        <button ng-click="addItem('{{item}}')">{{Item.name}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**RIGHT WAY**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
        <button ng-click="addItem(item)">{{Item.name}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```